# eclipse library mismatch error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mismatch

I have the following error on eclipse, how should I fix it?

```
[2015-05-27 13:43:38 - WPNOVA] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2015-05-27 13:43:38 - WPNOVA] Versions found are:
[2015-05-27 13:43:38 - WPNOVA] Path: D:\7\actionbarsherlock\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2015-05-27 13:43:38 - WPNOVA]  Length: 621451
[2015-05-27 13:43:38 - WPNOVA]  SHA-1: 5896b0a4e377ac4242eb2bc785220c1c4fc052f4
[2015-05-27 13:43:38 - WPNOVA] Path: D:\7\WPNOVA\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2015-05-27 13:43:38 - WPNOVA]  Length: 484258
[2015-05-27 13:43:38 - WPNOVA]  SHA-1: bd6479f5dd592790607e0504e66e0f31c2b4d308
[2015-05-27 13:43:38 - WPNOVA] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

Comment: Add some content with your question. This is not the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 jars having the same name but different content (not same size) in

> D:\7\actionbarsherlock\libs\android-support-v4.jar

and

> D:\7\WPNOVA\libs\android-support-v4.jar

This is not normal. Fix your Java Build Path in Eclipse (right click on your project > properties > Java Build Path > Libraries)